BottomSheetScaffold not showing
I tried the various methods I found as I am still learning and wish to update my previous question. I want a BottomSheetScaffold to display a file MailView.kt when a button is clicked.
But, it is still not showing up though there are no problems displayed, please.
The code for BottomSheetScaffold:
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()

  BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
        sheetContent = {
            MailView(scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState)
        },
        sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp, // Ensure the sheet is hidden initially
        content = {
            // Your main content

        },

    )

Code for button:
Button(
onClick = {scope.launch {
bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.expand()
 }
 },

Code in MailView.kt

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MailView(scaffoldState: BottomSheetScaffoldState) {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

   
            Text(
                text = "SOME TEXT..." )
               
           
    }



UPDATE:
I want to know how I can shift the content of the BottomSheetScaffold up a bit further to the top. The content seem to be positioned a little too low in the sheet for me. I need assistance on how to push the content up further.

Works for me, I cannot reproduce the problem. Please try to create a [mre]. Most of the code you provided won't be necessary to reproduce the problem. Remove it and make sure the remaining code actually reproduces the problem.

It's still working. The idea of a [mre] is that it should be reproducible. Please create a new project, use the code from your question and make it run. When you can reproduce the problem, use that code for the question (because it is now reproducible), if it isn't reproducible then find out what the differences are to your original code and narrow it down until you found the problem.

I don't understand what the question is. Please [edit] the question and update it with what you want to ask. Add/remove code as necessary and make sure to describe in detail what the problem is and what you want to achieve.

I still don't get it. What do you want, and where? Please either change the code so it produces what the screenshot shows or replace the screenshot with what the code actually produces (only the code from the question is relevant). I don't see any similarities except they both have a bottom sheet. Then add another screenshot that you edit so it shows how you want the result to look like. This makes it clear what you want to achieve.

That said, please make the edits to your question count. The last three edits didn't improve the question at all. Before saving the next edit take a step back and verify that the updated question will be in top shape and can easily be answered without the need for additional clarifying comments. Comments are not intended for a discussion. Your question is supposed to stand on its own. Please carefully read [ask] to make sure the question is as good as it can be. Make it count.

Updated question... Hope it is clearer and makes more sense now? So sorry for being such a novice.
